# Multiple return statements issue in python

Tags: python, numpy, return

I wrote a function which takes training dataframe and testing data frame as inputs.

In this function I'm creating three variables train, test and target

```
def rem_miss_vals(trainDF, testDF):
    trainDF = trainDF[np.isfinite(trainDF)]
    testDF = testDF[np.isfinite(testDF)]
    train = trainDF.values
    train = train[0::, 1:]
    target = train[0::, 0]
    test = testDF.values
    return train, test, target
```

I want to use the train, test and target in the below function

```
def get_variable_rankings(trainingset, targetset, testset):
    logit = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
    logreg = RFE(logit, 1)
    logreg.fit(trainingset, targetset)
    logitPredictions = logreg.predict(testset)
    variablerankings =  logreg.ranking_
    variablerankings = variablerankings.tolist()
    return variablerankings
```

ACTUAL CODE:

when I called these functions in main() function I received the error: train is not defined

```
rem_miss_vals(trainDF, testDF)
get_variable_rankings(train, target, test)
```

In the rem_miss_vals() I'm clearly returning them but I don't understand whay am I not able to use the train, target and test in the get_variable_rankings() function

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to assign the return values to some variables, so that they are in scope:

```
train, test, target = rem_miss_vals(trainDF, testDF)
variablerankings = get_variable_rankings(train, target, test)
```

Alternatively, splat them directly to the next function:

```
variablerankings = get_variable_rankings(*rem_miss_vals(trainDF, testDF))
```

Comment: Is referring to unpacking as "splat" or "splatting" popular with python users?

Comment: Yeah, `*` is often called the _splat operator_.